# Problem with LibreOffice Installation

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

I'm installing LibreOffice on my elementary OS, i have tried with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and finally `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

But when i open LibreOffice from Applications, the pc go to "suspend" can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain that " update and upgrade(dist)" part? What exact commands did you use? (hint: edit your post to add new information to it)

Comment: I added the edit

Comment: What do you mean by suspend.Does it go to sleep , turn off or the screen turns off.

Comment: screen tuns off, like the system crashed

Answer (score 1):

If you have a program you have installed that gives you a problem, try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get -f install
libreoffice
```

"sudo -f install" essentially fixes bad installs and missing dependencies/libraries/whatever.